# Leaving a comment in review removes my upvotes on other comments

Tags: bug, comments, review

Sometimes while reviewing, I upvote an existing comment and then decide to add one of my own before moving on. Interestingly, once I add my comment, my upvotes on other comments disappear as if I had never made them - I can upvote them again, and am allowed to remove that second upvote.

I know for sure this behavior occurs in the First Posts, Late Answers, and Close Votes review queues, and I wouldn't be surprised if it affects all queues.

Comment: If you check back in another tab, are they still gone, or is it just a visual glitch in /review/*?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Oh... it appears that comment upvotes aren't committed until the review task is complete. If I skip the task after upvoting a comment, the upvote has no effect. That's bizarre and kind of unfortunate, but there's still a bug here, I think.

Comment: That's quite strange. Not sure if that deserves a bug of its own, or just rephrasing this one to include both of those behaviors.