# Make comment upvotes and flags in review queues be committed immediately

Tags: feature-request, comments, review

While investigating [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273449/leaving-a-comment-in-review-removes-my-upvotes-on-other-comments), I realized that upvotes and flags *on comments* from review queues are not committed until the review is completed. That is, if I skip the review, it will be as though I had never upvoted/flagged those comments.

I frequently see and upvote insightful comments while reviewing a post that I don't feel sure about, so I think it's important that such actions be committed even if the review is not completed.

Comment: This is only comment upvotes and comment flags, not other upvotes and flags? Interesting.

Comment: @NathanTuggy probably there is a transaction behind the scenes, good chance this is a bug after all.

Comment: Interesting. I always assumed that comment flags went through the network just like anything else and were applied immediately. Good find.